# Javascript : How to process function's argument even if it undefined

Tags: javascript

I am creating a function to check if given value is empty or not, if it undefined, equals to empty string, or has zero length it will returns true. Here is what i'm done

```
isEmpty(value){
    if(typeof(value)=='undefined'){
        return true;
    }
    else if(value==''||value.length==0){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

but when i evaluate some undefined variable for example isEmpty(foo) it will throw an uncaught reference error, but i want return true, how to do that?

```js
function isEmpty(value) {
  if (typeof(value) == 'undefined') {
    return true;
  } else if (value == '' || value.length == 0) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

console.log(isEmpty(value))
```

Comment: the variable which you;re trying to pass from outside should be defined. like `let x;` If the variable itself will not be defined then it will throw the error.

Comment: You might also want to check `value == null`

Comment: As @kaushik said the variable should be defined before passing. Unless you should use things like: `try { isEmpty } catch (e) { }`.

Comment: Try like this [`fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/g1w3sxzb/)

Answer (score 3):

You are understanding [Undefined](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined) wrong

> Undefined means a variable has been declared, but the value of that
>   variable has not yet been defined(Not assigned a value yet). For example:

```js
function isEmpty(value){

// or simply value===undefined will also do in your case
  if(typeof(value)==='undefined'||value==''||value.length==0){
        return true;
    }
  return false;
        
}
let foo; // declared but not assigned a value so its undefined at the moment
console.log(isEmpty(foo))
```

Add On -What is Uncaught  ReferenceError: "x" is not defined.

> There is a non-existent variable referenced somewhere. This variable
>   needs to be declared , or you need make sure it is available in your
>   current script or scope.

So clearly you are not referencing your variable anywhere in the context ,so you get that exception.[Follow Up Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Not_defined)

This is how you can check that variable is in the scope or it is declared or not ,by catching the reference Error

```js
// Check if variable is declared or not

//let value;
try {
  value;
} catch (e) {
  if (e.name == "ReferenceError") {
    console.log("variable not declared yet")
  }


}

// or the function approach


function isEmpty(value){

// or simply value===undefined will also do in your case
  if(typeof(value)==='undefined'||value==''||value.length==0){
        return true;
    }
  return false;
        
}


try {
  isEmpty(value);
} catch (e) {
  if (e.name == "ReferenceError") {
    console.log("variable not declared yet")
  }
}
```

Comment: You don't really need the `typeof` here. `value === undefined` should be fine since `value` is guaranteed to at least be declared.

Comment: Yes,you are absolutely right ,but that's how it is stated in the question .I will still make a add on @MarkMeyer

Comment: what if that variable does not exist?

Comment: Updated my answer @MatiusNugrohoAryanto

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for, a test of `value===undefined` first fixes.

```js
const isEmpty = (value) => value===undefined||typeof(value)==='undefined'||value===''||value.length===0;

let foo;
let bar = 'test';

console.log(isEmpty());
console.log(isEmpty(foo));
console.log(isEmpty(bar));
```

Comment: what if i want isEmpty(xxx) to be evaluated as true even xxx never declared anywhere

Comment: I think it is important to understand the error is thrown at the point of the call, **not** inside your test method. so `console.log(isEmpty(myUndeclaredVariable));` would cause the error. Not the `isEmpty` function itself.

Comment: i knew, when variable is not declared it doesn't exist in memory does it? then i want examine as true even the variable isn't exist yet